# Which Test for Divergence/Conv should be used with a sin(n) in the numerator?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I see that quite a few questions on infinite series have been asked recently and figured why not continue the trend!

going through my lectures and textbooks, I understand $\sin^2n$ is bounded by 0 and 1, I understand that something like $\cos\pi n$ is just an alternating series in disguise, however, I cannot come up with a solid strategy for when it is just $\sin(n)$

So for example, my problem I am currently stuck on: 
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty {\sin(n)\over (5+2n^2)} $$

Now I know how you would tackle something like $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sin({1\over n}) $ but the n term isn't attached to the sin function. In my problem above I believe that is what is screwing with me.

My intuition tells me to do a comparison test to $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sin({1\over n^2}) $

If someone could kindly explain it would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's easier than you think. In the long run (that is for big $n$) that $\sin$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Informally: $|\sin n|$ stays reasonable, $5+2n^2$ increases sort of fast, so sum is finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The numerator is $O(1)$ and denominator is $\Omega(n^2)$, so it should converge; try comparing it with $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: that was my intuition I guess I wasn't seeing why

Comment: @treehau5 Do you know about the [comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_test)? Observe that for any $n$ we have $\frac{\sin(n)}{5+2n^2} \leq \frac{1}{5+2n^2} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: yes, I guess my problem comes with the fact that the limit of sin(n) to infinity is -1 to 1

Comment: Well, $\sum_n \sin(\pi n)+\frac{1}{n^2}$ would not converge, but in your case the $\sin(n)$ is in the numerator and it becomes irrelevant as $n \to \infty$. What is important, the sequence converges absolutly.

Comment: How are you able to tell it converges absolutely without the ratio/root test?

Comment: Because $\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges absolutly and $\left|\frac{\sin(n)}{5+2n^2}\right| \leq \left|\frac{1}{5+2n^2}\right| \leq \left|\frac{1}{n^2}\right|$ as I pointed out before, see the aforementioned comparison test for more details.